# can`t resolve Node no longer exists error

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to use youtube xml to show some data but this error pops up.
In teory I even know what`s wrong

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$v.'?fields=title,yt:recorded,yt:statistics'))); //$v is video array
$title = (string)$xmlData->title;
$entry = $xmlData;

$namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
$yr = $entry->children((string)$namespaces['yt']);

// get <yt:recorded> node for date and replace yyyy-mm-dd to dd.mm.yyyy
$year = substr($yr->recorded, 0,4); 
$month = substr($yr->recorded, 5,2);
$day = substr($yr->recorded, 8,2);
$recorddate = $day.".".$month.".".$year;

// get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics, and here the problem starts (error appears if view count is 0 / node does not exist)
  $attrs = $yr->statistics->attributes(); 
      $viewCount = $attrs[(string)'viewCount']; 

                     { echo '<p>'.$recorddate.'<br>'.$title.'<br>'; 
                     if ($viewCount > 0)
 echo $viewCount.'</p></div>';
else
echo '(show some other text)</p></div>';      }
```

I know that to resolve this you must tell php that node is string but I still have not managed to do it without breaking the rest of code

Comment: Post the XML input as well as the complete error message. The line number is important, be sure to mention which line this is.

Answer (score 3):

```
$viewCount = 0;
if ($yr->statistics->count() > 0) {
$attrs = $yr->statistics->attributes();
 $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount'];
}
```

nice, but for those with php prior 5.3.0 this will not work :(
 any better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Solution that should work also for php users <= 5.2

```
  $viewCount = 0;
if (count($yr->statistics) > 0) {
    $attrs = $yr->statistics->attributes(); 
    $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue. Seems like you need to check if any statistics are available first, then try to access the attributes.

```
$viewCount = 0;
if ($yr->statistics->count() > 0) {
    $attrs = $yr->statistics->attributes(); 
    $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount'];
}
```

YouTube doesn't seem to add the attributes if the video hasn't been viewed. So if you've got a video with a view count of 0, YouTube doesn't put the viewCount as 0, it just omits it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using casting correctly. This line does **NOT** cast the `SimpleXMLElement` object to a string. *(it cast the string `'viewCount'` to a string, which is non-sensical)*

```
$viewCount = $attrs[(string)'viewCount'];
```

This one does:

```
$viewCount = (string) $attrs['viewCount'];
```